# Gupshup IDE doesn't load

Tags: gupshup

I'm trying to create a WhatApp API bot using the IDE method. I'm stuck at trying to open the IDE. Either, it keeps showing "Creating your workspace" or get stuck in the iDE window with "null" showing in the "Explore" screen with a spinning cursor. Any inputs are appreciated.

[image: IDE loading forever]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same error. But this link helped me for now.
These up options are not covered in the article. The rest are the same.

1. Do you want to enable bot-script? Yes
2. Do you want to initialize a Git Repository and Link it With Gupshup? Yes

Hope this link will help
https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/gupshup-bot-library-for-node.